# Lambda code works on node v8.10 but not nodejs v10.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working through a lambda course which was done using v8.10. I am trying to use nodejs v10.x since that is what I want to use for my project in the future.

I am not understanding why the "const uuid = require('uuid');" line is throwing an import error only in nodejs v10 but in v8.10 the code runs just fine.

Code:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Get the event to our S3POC class - " + JSON.stringify(event));

    const newUUID = uuid.v4();

    console.log("The file name is:" + newUUID);

    //put our sentence into the s3 bucket
    return s3.putObject({
        Bucket: "helloworld-s3.arkhadbot.com",
        Key: "test" + ".json"
    });
};
```

Error

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"e9c300ff-d12e-47b9-a45a-996a1f78b5f5"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: e9c300ff-d12e-47b9-a45a-996a1f78b5f5 Version: $LATEST
2019-09-12T12:18:34.743Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)","    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)","    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)","    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]}
END RequestId: e9c300ff-d12e-47b9-a45a-996a1f78b5f5
REPORT RequestId: e9c300ff-d12e-47b9-a45a-996a1f78b5f5  Duration: 5098.92 ms    Billed Duration: 5100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB  
XRAY TraceId: 1-5d7a3795-41360f9ed871797c8ff32c3e   SegmentId: 4f526b023d16ac66 Sampled: false  
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.ImportModuleError
```

Comment: are you reinstalling your modules after node version change?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that? UUID should be built into AWS like aws-sdk is. I have not installed or done anything to add custom/3rd party libraries to lambda yet

Comment: sorry my bad i did not realise this, looking at the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), you need to specify what version of uuid you want. try ```const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')```

Comment: same error:

  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'",
  "trace": [

Comment: Believe that uuid/v4 etc. are now external packages so you have to npm install uuid locally and bundle it with your Lambda function.

Comment: jarmod I will have to google how to do that and repost here later.

Comment: I think its removed due to security reason and due to secuirty reason support of v6 stoped in AWS lamda. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/security-bulletin-node-uuid-unsafe-fallback-mathrandom-cve-2015-8851

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since node.js v10 aws lambda does not support importing libraries from lambda itself.

from the docs :

> A deployment package is a ZIP archive that contains your function code
>   and dependencies. You need to create a deployment package if you use
>   the Lambda API to manage functions, or if you need to include
>   libraries and dependencies other than the AWS SDK.
>
> If your function
>   depends on libraries other than the SDK for JavaScript, install them
>   to a local directory with NPM, and include them in your deployment
>   package. You can also include the SDK for JavaScript if you need a
>   newer version than the one included on the runtime, or to ensure that
>   the version doesn't change in the future.

More about [AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

**Update 02/05/2020:**

node.js 8.10 is now deprecated, you should use node.js 10 or 12.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As per accepted answer, it's now required that lambda won't have third party support directly. (because Node 8 version is deprecated now which might've still accepted).

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
// const uuid = require('uuid'); comment this out

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("Get the event to our S3POC class - " + JSON.stringify(event));

    // const newUUID = context.awsRequestId();
    const newUUID = context.awsRequestId;

    console.log("The file name is:" + newUUID);

    //put our sentence into the s3 bucket
    return s3.putObject({
        Bucket: "helloworld-s3.arkhadbot.com",
        Key: "test" + ".json"
    });
};
```

AWS Request IDs might look like so: requestId: 'daf9dc5e-1628-4437-9e2d-2998efaa73b4'

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. What I have done was initialize npm in the lambda's respective folder and add the uuid package into it.