# Upgrade from Nodejs8.x to Nodejs10.x or Nodejs12.x gives error - Cannot find module 'is-buffer'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Today I found out that AWS is no longer supporting Nodejs8.x so I foolishly upgraded all my Lambda functions to Nodejs10.x without testing for breaking changes. Now NONE of my functions work as they did.

I just keep getting this error: Cannot find module 'is-buffer'. I searched around but have no idea what's causing this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code that is breaking?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910112/9931092